compare 2 different dates with same cells
i have the following table:



date
cat
val




01/02/2024
cat A
7


01/02/2024
cat B
4


01/02/2024
cat C
5


02/02/2024
cat A
9


02/02/2024
cat B
2


02/02/2024
cat C
3


02/02/2024
cat D
6


02/02/2024
cat E
8


03/02/2024
cat B
4


03/02/2024
cat C
7


03/02/2024
cat D
3


03/02/2024
cat E
1



my goal is to compare the date with the same cat (e.g. 2/2/24 & 1/2/24 has cat A, B, C, hence (9+2+3)/(7+4+5) = 0.875)
the output should be like this



date
%




01/02/2024
NA


02/02/2024
87.50%


03/02/2024
78.95%



01/02/24 NA because theres nothing to compare before the date
other than doing it manually, or pivoting to make the cat as columns instead of row then still do it manually but "easier", i havent found the efficient way to solve this

Try the following formula-
=LET(x,GROUPBY($B$2:$B$13,$C$2:$C$13,SUM,,0,,$A$2:$A$13=$E3),
y,GROUPBY($B$2:$B$13,$C$2:$C$13,SUM,,0,,$A$2:$A$13=$E3-1),
z,XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(x,1),CHOOSECOLS(y,1),CHOOSECOLS(y,2)),
SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(x,z),ISNUMBER(z)),2))/SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(x,z),ISNUMBER(z)),3)))

Single cell formula-
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A13),BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A13),LAMBDA(r,
LET(x,GROUPBY(B2:B13,C2:C13,SUM,,0,,A2:A13=r),
y,GROUPBY(B2:B13,C2:C13,SUM,,0,,A2:A13=r-1),
z,XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(x,1),CHOOSECOLS(y,1),CHOOSECOLS(y,2)),
SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(x,z),ISNUMBER(z)),2))/SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(x,z),ISNUMBER(z)),3))))))

Note: You must format the date cells as date format and result cell as percentage format.

